# Animation diagonal divs using bootstrap 4 only when the div enters the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to run an animation on 2 diagonal divs.
The first one should appear from the right, the second one should appear from the left. I tried different solution found on internet since it's my first time doing animation, but nothing worked as expected.

```
<section class="page-section h-100 text-center text-white" id="services" >
    <div class="container-fluid toLeft" id="slideInRight">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Sei in cerca di un PT?</h1>
            <p class="font-weight-light">Potrai entrare in contatto con il personal trainer perfetto per te. Inizia subito il tuo percorso verso il corpo dei tuoi sogni</p>
            <button id="signInAsUser" type="button" class="btn btn-dark loginService">Iscriviti come cliente</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid toRight" id="slideInLeft">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Sei un PT in cerca di clienti?</h1>
          <p class="font-weight-light">Potrai offrire le tue conoscenze tecniche agli utenti, aiutandoli a raggiungere i propri obiettivi</p>
          <button id="signInAsPt" type="button" class="btn btn-danger loginService">Iscriviti come PT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4b6283m9/

Animation code:

```
$('.toLeft').each( function (i)){
  var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
  var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
  if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
     $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) which work without JavaScript also; For your requirement, we just need to play with `margin` property to get the effect that we're aiming for... the animation is set for a speed of `3 seconds` which you can change... also the speed curve of the animation, which is currently set to `ease-in-out`;

**UPDATE** in light of questioner's comment below:
the animation will trigger only when the divs (which we want to animate) enter the viewport

**working snippet** below:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top_of_element = $("#slideInRight").offset().top;
  var bottom_of_element = $("#slideInRight").offset().top + $("#slideInRight").outerHeight();
  var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
  var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)) {
    //console.log("the element is visible, do something");
    if ($("#slideInRight").hasClass("toLeft")) {} else {
      $("#slideInRight").addClass("toLeft");
    }
    if ($("#slideInLeft").hasClass("toRight")) {} else {
      $("#slideInLeft").addClass("toRight");
    }
  } else {
    // console.log("the element is not visible, do something else");
  }
});
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8rem 0;
}

.toLeft {
  background: #b31c2a;
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  animation: enterFromLeft 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes enterFromLeft {
  from {
    margin-left: -90%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

.toLeft .container {
  transform: skewY(2deg);
}

.toRight {
  background: black;
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  animation: enterFromRight 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes enterFromRight {
  from {
    margin-left: 90%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

.toRight .container {
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p>
  The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
  architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia
  dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid
  ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" 1914 translation by H. Rackham "But I must explain to you
  how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects,
  dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain
  of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
  from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by
  Cicero in 45 BC "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia
  deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
  assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut
  reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat." 1914 translation by H. Rackham "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms
  of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from
  toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided.
  But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle
  of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."

</p>

<hr/>
<p>
  The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
  architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia
  dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid
  ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" 1914 translation by H. Rackham "But I must explain to you
  how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects,
  dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain
  of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
  from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by
  Cicero in 45 BC "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia
  deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
  assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut
  reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat." 1914 translation by H. Rackham "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms
  of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from
  toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided.
  But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle
  of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."

</p>

<section class="page-section h-100 text-center text-white" id="services">
  <div class="container-fluid " id="slideInRight"> /* toLeft */
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Sei in cerca di un PT?</h1>
      <p class="font-weight-light">Potrai entrare in contatto con il personal trainer perfetto per te. Inizia subito il tuo percorso verso il corpo dei tuoi sogni</p>
      <button id="signInAsUser" type="button" class="btn btn-dark loginService">Iscriviti come cliente</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid " id="slideInLeft"> /* toRight */
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Sei un PT in cerca di clienti?</h1>
      <p class="font-weight-light">Potrai offrire le tue conoscenze tecniche agli utenti, aiutandoli a raggiungere i propri obiettivi</p>
      <button id="signInAsPt" type="button" class="btn btn-danger loginService">Iscriviti come PT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you! Can i ask how i can run that animation only when the divs are visible?

PS: Edited the question with the animation code i'm using right now for playing the animations only when the element is visible

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks for the help!